# Queensland Australia Hospital and Health Service Boundaries Covid-19 Database

Tags: medical, australia, covid19

I'm searching for a database (or spreadsheet) containing the number of Covid-19 cases for every Hospital and Health Service boundaries in Queensland, Australia. That is, the cases in Queensland Australia for each [**HHS Boundary**](https://www.health.qld.gov.au/maps).

The Queensland Government already issues the [**current breakdown**](https://www.qld.gov.au/health/conditions/health-alerts/coronavirus-covid-19/current-status/current-status-and-contact-tracing-alerts) for each Hospital and Health Service Boundary, but these are current cases. Further, there are daily media releases, such as [**this one**](https://www.health.qld.gov.au/news-events/doh-media-releases/releases/queensland-novel-coronavirus-covid-19-update-2020-04-13),  which break down the Covid-19 cases per region. It would be possible to scour the media releases one by one, and create my own database. However, I was hoping someone has done that already. Especially since the media releases are not in a consistent format, particularly the early ones.

I would ultimately like to create a map showing the growth of Covid-19 in Queensland, Australia. I already have the HHS boundaries which I downloaded **[here](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/detail.page?fid=%7BA4661F6D-0013-46EE-A446-A45F01A64D46%7D)**. I just need the Covid-19 data to link with it.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Australia and links in that article. There is some good data collated there and it seems to be kept up to date on a regular basis (also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics_of_the_COVID-19_pandemic_in_Australia). Btw if you are going to do it on the web give QGIS and QGIS2Web a go - seriously nice tools - no portals needed